# Reading parameters from TestNG file

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng

I successfully implemented several tests within TestNG framework, where parameters are being read from xml file.
Here is the example block that is executed as first:

```
@Parameters({ "country" })
@BeforeSuite(alwaysRun = true)
public void prepareRequest(String country, ITestContext cnt) {
LoginInfoRequestParm loginParms = new LoginInfoRequestParm(country);
Headers reqHeaders = new Headers();
reqHeaders.setHeaders(loginParms);
}
```

The problem/question is, why does it work only if the ITestContext is specified? Once it is removed, the overall suite is broken and it will never come to the specified method prepareRequest(). I was not able to debug it, because I cannt set breakpoint before the method to be able to see what is going on in TestNG itself.
Thank you for your explanation.

Comment: Share the exception you get when you remove _ITestContext_ ? I tested using sample script and it passed even if I included/excluded _ITestContext_.

Answer (score 0):

To get out of this situation, try something like this

```
String myPar = context.getCurrentXmlTest().getParameter("country");
    if (myPar == null) {
        myPar = "INDIA";
    }
```

now myPar can be used, only thing here is if you run class for debug or any other purpose then we are using INDIA. if we run from testng.xml file then it will take values from that file.